# transform reverse engineered physical data model into conceptual entity relationship diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have reverse engineered a physical data model from an existing db using enterprise architect. It looks similar to this, which IMHO is an erm too:

[image]

Can I transform this into an erm like this?:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not automatically. You are trying an abstraction from physics. Only a human can do that. So you need to do that manually. The reverse however is possible via a transformation. In that case you take an abstract class model and transform it into one (or many) physical representations.